# obj.nextElementSibling || obj.nextSibling

Tags: javascript, dom

there is test code:

```
<body>
    <div id="abc">1</div>
    <div>2</div>

    <script>
        var id = document.getElementById("abc");
        var div = id.nextElementSibling || id.nextSibling;
        // change order 
        var div1 = id.nextSibling || id.nextElementSibling;

        alert(div.textContent)   // alert: 2
        alert(div1.textContent)  // alert nothing
    </script>
</body>
```

this code is runing on `chrome brower`, first alert() pop-up `2`, but second alert() pop-up nothing. why?

Comment: `console.log(div.nodeName)` vs. `console.log(div1.nodeName)`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
    <div id="abc">1</div><div>2</div> //2, 2
    <div id="abc">1</div>x<div>2</div> //2, x
```

the problem is that with or, only the first part of the condition is evaluated (when true). So your second call returns the string (spaces) - see the *nextSibling* method description bellow.

try also this change:

```
alert('"' + div1.textContent + '"') // the second call will return "   " (with also line break inside)
```

---

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nextsibling.asp

> The difference between this property and nextElementSibling, is that nextSibling returns the next sibling node as an element node, a text node or a comment node, while nextElementSibling returns the next sibling node as an element node (ignores text and comment nodes).